# AWK is not printing the result

Tags: awk

I want to write a simple `awk` command in Ubuntu (version 14.04), but it is not returning anything.

```
$ cat sample.csv
001,Text1,Val1
002,Text2,Val2
003,Text3,Val3

$ cat sample.csv|awk -F',''{for (i=0;i<2,i++){gsub(/Text[0-9]/,"Text"\1+i); print $0}}'
```

returns nothing. The expected result should be:

```
001,Text1,Val1
001,Text2,Val1
002,Text2,Val2
002,Text3,Val2
003,Text3,Val3
003,Text4,Val3
```

It is working perfectly in other machine where Red hat Linux is there.
Do I have to install anything to make it work? The shell is bash.

```
$ which awk
/usr/bin/awk
```

Comment: There are quite a few typos here: a comma instead of a semicolon in the `for()`, a space missing after `-F','`, the quoting on `gsub` arguments is flaky... are you sure you copied it well?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem has nothing to do with `gawk` as you wrote in [your](https://askubuntu.com/a/587673/367165) answer. The `awk` script in your question is simply wrong and can't work:

Compare your

```
cat sample.csv|awk -F',''{for (i=0;i<2,i++){gsub(/Text[0-9]/,"Text"\1+i); print $0}}'
```

and a working version

```
cat sample.csv|awk -F',' '{for (i=0;i<2;i++){gsub(/Text[0-9]/,"Text"$1+i); print $0}}'
```

---

And I would use this

```
awk -F, '{for (i=0;i<2;i++){gsub(/Text[0-9]/,"Text"$1+i); print $0}}' sample.csv
```

Output

```
001,Text1,Val1
001,Text2,Val1
002,Text2,Val2
002,Text3,Val2
003,Text3,Val3
003,Text4,Val3
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure what you are trying to do but maybe you need a script like the one below.

```bsh
awk -F, 'BEGIN{OFS=FS}
{
    match($2,/[0-9]+$/)
    n=substr($2,RSTART,RLENGTH)
    for (i=0;i<2;i++){
        gsub(/[0-9]+$/,n+i,$2)
        print
    }
}' sample.csv
```

Answer (score -1):

The command (in body of the question there was a small issue in the command, which I have corrected below) works good after installing `gawk`

```
cat sample.csv|awk -F, '{for (i=0;i<2;i++){gsub(/Text[0-9]/,"Text"$1+i); print $0}}'
```

Executed `sudo apt-get install gawk` to install `gawk`.